# Liferay can't edit folder permissions in a particular site

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am struggling with a weird problem. I can't change folder permissions on folders inside a particular site. When I click the edit permissions link on the folders the modal window shows up empty. I am logged in with a user with the Administrator role. The same problem happens with web content and document library folders.

I am running Liferay Portal Enterprise Edition 6.2.10 EE GA1.

Best regards,

Fabrício Sperandio

Comment: It happens for all folders and web contents inside this particular site.

Comment: You have to check roles and permissions tables in your database, Maybe some roles are missing for your user(It can happen even for OmniAdmin). Or you have deployed ext module and damaged your .jsp files

Comment: As you are an EE customer, you should be opening a LESA ticket for support.

Comment: may be something about the scope of the permissions ?